# How to say "why do so hard since an easy way available here"

Tags: phrase-request

Common phrase to say "why do so hard since an easy way available here"
Id much appreciated to see both formal and informal ways

Comment: You mean "Why work hard when there is an easy way to do it" or something like that?

Comment: Of course mattew

Comment: Common? Where did you see or hear it?

Answer (score 1):

More formal:

"Why do something the hard way when there is an easier way?"

Less formal:

"Why kill yourself when you don't have to?"

Comment: You can use "Why working so hard" too.

Answer (score 0):

You can say, "here's a shortcut". It's not excessively colloquial, but neither is it particularly formal.

> **Shortcut** *noun*
>   1.1 An accelerated way of doing or achieving something.
>   *‘teaching no longer offered a shortcut to secure employment’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shortcut)

A suitable formal equivalent would depend on the application - e.g. "This *proof* is more *elegant*." or "That *route* is *more accessible*."

Colloquial expressions can depend on the regional dialect. For example, your quote uses Asian English expressions (*so hard* = *more difficult*); Australians might say "Do it this way, mate - done in two shakes."

> **Two shakes of a lamb's tail** *idiom*
>   Something that can be done in “two shakes of a lamb's tail” can be done very quickly: “The repairman said he could fix our tire in two shakes of a lamb's tail, and he was right: we were back on the road in ten minutes.”
>   [- Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/two-shakes-of-a-lamb-s-tail)